# Android App can't find file

Tags: android, xml, filenotfoundexception, domparser

I'm working on my first Android app and I'm trying to parse an XML file using a DOM parser. I'm using an absolute file path, but the compiler still can't find my file and I'm not sure why.

This is the message that LogCat gave me. (Note: I'm using a Mac.)

> 03-10 11:52:16.427: W/System.err(929): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Users/leedownen/Desktop/AndroidApp/AssignmentGrabber/src/mus/school/tools/assignmentsbystudent.xml
>   (No such file or directory)

```
    package mus.school.tools;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import java.io.File;


    public class AssignmentGrabberActivity extends Activity  {
    class Async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

        private String results = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String myURL = url[0];

            try  {

                    File fXmlFile = new File(myURL);
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                    //System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
                    //System.out.println("-----------------------");

                    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                       Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                       if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                          Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                        results = results + "\n" + ("Class : " + getTagValue("ClassName", eElement)) + 
                          ("Period : " + getTagValue("period", eElement))
                             + ("Day : " + getTagValue("Day", eElement));
                       }
                    }
                  } 
             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             return results;

        }

         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String results) 
        {
            this.results = results;
        }


         private String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) 
         {
                NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

                    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

                return nValue.getNodeValue();
        }


        public String getResults()
        {
            return results;

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        Async myAsync = new Async();
        myAsync.execute("/Users/leedownen/Desktop/AndroidApp/AssignmentGrabber/src/mus/school/tools/assignmentsbystudent.xml");

        tv.setText(myAsync.getResults());
        setContentView(tv);

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can use a absolute filepath from your desktop in an android app?
The emulator nor your phone can access that file from within the app, so logically it doesn't work.

You should add your file to the res dir or the assets dir and learn to access them.

Also, you are using `AsyncTask` wrongly. You can't fetch the results in the onCreate, since you start the background task, and immediately try to fetch the results. You should setting that text also in the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`. That will run after the task is complete.

Comment: Ah, I see. How would I get onPostExecute() to print the String "results" on the UI since AsyncTask can't access my TextView object?

Comment: I think you should use a `TextView` thats defined in the layout you set as content view. Then you can use `findviewbyid` to retrieve that textview and set the string in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: Here's the code that has my TextView:                                  `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         TextView tv = new TextView(this);`        Here's the line of code from my class that extends AsycnTask: `TextView tv = (TextView) View.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);` I not sure what the name of my `View` object is to call `findViewbyID` on. Can you tell from these snippets of code?

Answer (score 0):

Better you put it on the row file and then fetch it from the code using

```
//assets/assignmentsbystudent.xml
```

and then try to set the path above mentioned.Hope this will work.